Prepare E2E test on ApplicationReadyEvent Java Springboot
I'm trying to create an E2E test for my ApplicationReadyEvent event of my component, the problem is that I need to create some infrastructure with LocalStack before the event is sent. The problem is that as soon as the test is ran, the ApplicationReadyEvent is triggered before the beforeEach and the test methods, so I'm not really able to mock or prepare my infrastructure.
I would love some insight on the matter.
This is my class:
@Component
public class ApplicationStartup implements ApplicationListener<ApplicationReadyEvent> {
    private final MyService myService;

    public ApplicationStartup(MyService myService) {
        this.myService = myService;
    }

    @Override
    public void onApplicationEvent(final ApplicationReadyEvent event) {
        myService.myMethod();
    }
}

This is my test class:
@SpringBootTest
@Testcontainers
class ApplicationStartupE2E {

    @Container
    static LocalStackContainer localStack = LocalStackConstants.createLocalStackContainer();

    @SpyBean
    private MyService myService;


    @DynamicPropertySource
    static void overrideProperties(DynamicPropertyRegistry registry) {
        registry.add("amazon.aws.region", () -> localStack.getRegion());
        registry.add("amazon.aws.access-key", () -> localStack.getAccessKey());
        registry.add("amazon.aws.secret-key", () -> localStack.getSecretKey());

        registry.add("amazon.s3.endpoint", () -> localStack.getEndpointOverride(LocalStackContainer.Service.S3).toString());
        registry.add("amazon.dynamodb.endpoint", () -> localStack.getEndpointOverride(LocalStackContainer.Service.DYNAMODB).toString());

    }

    @BeforeEach
    void setUp() {
        LocalStackFunctions.doStuff(localStack);
    }

    @AfterEach
    void tearDown() {
        LocalStackFunctions.doStuff(localStack);
    }

    @Test
    void shouldTriggerProcess() {
       // Additional mocks if needed
       // Trigger event
       // Assert
    }
}



Have you tried a static constructor i guess they run before otherwise i think you can hook before the event this is what i meant https://salahuddin-s.medium.com/ways-to-execute-code-at-application-startup-in-spring-boot-31ac310e476e

Hi @NicoS. thanks, this would work as expected, but I would then need to create a different test class whenever I want to test a different case of the same method. Is there any other way to achieve this?

@NicoS. in fact, I can't use the LocalStackContainer in the static block since it's not yet running... In the BeforeAll it's already running so I can use that, but still the issue is still the same... how do I manage different tests in the same class

Do i understand right you always want to restart the spring boot context so you can do something before the event?
